# Can I use the LastPass webapp from my PC and android app with the free plan?

Tags: lastpass

In the [pricing comparison](https://www.lastpass.com/pricing) it says that the free plan allows 1 device type but I'm not sure if that applies to my use case.

I'm only interested in using their web-app login from my PC to take password protected notes, and using the app in my android phone to do the same (I'm not going to use any password-storing functionality they have).

I'm not interested in installing anything in my PC (nor an extension for my browser).

Given my use case, am I "using" more than 1 device type?

If I wanted to test it myself, I would have to wait until the premium trial ends in 30 days to see if they prevent me from logging in from one of said devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users on the free tier could use Lastpass on any device type but they will be asked to choose one. then when trying to use it on a different device type they should "switch" the device type.

---

I'm on the free tier and I'm currently using the Lastpass' Android app. When I try to open Lastpass on the web, it shows the following:

[image]

> ## 3 device switches left
>
> Active device type:Mobile
>
> You can only use LastPass for free on one type of device. Switch up to 3 times to find the right option for you.
>
> [Learn about switching your device type](https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/what-can-i-expect-to-change-for-lastpass-free-on-march-16-2021)